# Data rate for 1080p@30fps Video in BT.656 8~10 bit format?

Tags: video-transmitter

What is the data rate for 1080p@30fps video in BT.656 8~10 bit format? Does the [MAX9271 serailizer](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX9271.pdf) support FHD@30 in BT.656 format? According to the datasheet the serial data rate is 1.5Gbps.

Answer (score 2):

1080p30 has a pixel clock of 74.25 MHz (2200 pixels × 1125 lines × 30 fps). In 4:2:2 subsampled format there are 20 bits per pixel. That's 1.485 Gbps.